# what is march parameter when compile a c file

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation

I saw these two kinds of make parameters:

```
make -march=corei7-avx xxxx xxxx 
make -march-icelake-server xxxx xxx
```

arch is understood, what's the m meaning?

Where can I find which arch can be used? ( I google but nothing )

What will 'make' do when using this parameter -march=xxxx?

It will compile specific x86 instruction in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are definitely *NOT* make parameters.  If you try to run `make` like that you'll get an error:

```
$ make -march=core17
make: invalid option -- 'a'
make: invalid option -- 'c'
make: invalid option -- '='
make: invalid option -- 'c'
```

However these are valid options for GCC; you can read about them in the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/Submodel-Options.html).